# Remote Desktop to KVM Virtual Machine on Centos 7

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, centos7

I have a virtual machine created on centos7. I want to remote connect to it via another computer besides the host. I can not seem find how to access it. I have it set up with a username and password. I have connected via the host machine but I need to now access it via another computer.

I am on a windows 8 computer trying to connect to it.

Comment: Let's start from simple debug:
1. Can you ping VM's IP from your windows machine? If no - can you do it from KVM node?
2. If yes - can you telnet to port 22 from windows machine?

Comment: I can only ping the Host Ip from my windows Computer. But I can not ping any VM. I can ping my Windows Computer from the KVM.

Answer (score 0):

In order to connect to the VM over the network from another machine besides the host system, the VM's networking will need to be configured in "bridged mode".  If you used virt-manager to create the VM, check the NIC device on the "virtual hardware details" screen, and verify that the mode is set to "bridged".

Comment: It is! The networked is bridged how it should be

Comment: Is the VM able to ping the other machine's IP address?  Is there a local firewall running on the VM, or on the host system, that may be blocking external access to the VM?  On the CentOS host, try running "systemctl stop firewalld.service" and then see if you can connect.

Comment: I can ping my Windows machine from the KVM, but I can get no contact to the VM from my windows machine. I can tho ping the host. So I am thinking there is a firewall up on the VMs